# Single row fetch when two records are common

Tags: sql

```
Fromjourney ToJourney   KM
Delhi       Mumbai      1000
Mumbai      Delhi       1000
Gurgaon     Noida       50
Noida       Gurgaon     50
Ghaziabad   Faridabad   60
Faridabad   Ghaziabad   60
Delhi       Meerut      80
Meerut      Delhi       80
```

I have three column `from`, `To` and `KM`.

I want single row data when From To have same city 
like From- Mumbai, To-Delhi
     To- Delhi, From-Mumbai

Ι want single row of this data

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Which rdbms you are using? Oracle/sql-server/mysql - Always add proper tags. Anyways, it looks like it does not matter for your question. Go through these SQL tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.Fromjourney,T1.ToJourney
  ,T2.*
from TestTable T1
left join TestTable T2 
  on T1.Fromjourney = T2.ToJourney
  and T1.ToJourney = T2.Fromjourney
  and T1.Fromjourney < T2.Fromjourney 
where T2.Fromjourney is not null
```

---

```
| Fromjourney | ToJourney | Fromjourney | ToJourney |   KM |
|-------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|------|
|       Delhi |    Mumbai |      Mumbai |     Delhi | 1000 |
|     Gurgaon |     Noida |       Noida |   Gurgaon |   50 |
|   Faridabad | Ghaziabad |   Ghaziabad | Faridabad |   60 |
|       Delhi |    Meerut |      Meerut |     Delhi |   80 |
```

---

[DEMO - SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c958f/17/0)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
select t.*
from testtable t
where Fromjourney < ToJourney
union all
select t.*
from testtable t
where Fromjourney > ToJourney and
      not exists (select 1
                  from testtable t2
                  where t2.Fromjourney = t.ToJourney and t2.ToJourney = t.Fromjourney);
```